# White Space in stacked bar using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, stacked-chart

I'm using chart.js version 2.7.2 to plot some charts.
The chart is a bar chart, and i'm using a time axis to set the dataset points.

If i use a normal graph the dataset is showed correctly, but if i set the stacked axis, at the first item the render show a strange white space!

Look at the charts, with **stacked:false** its all ok, with **stacked:true** there's a strange white space at the first bar!
Is there a way to remove that white space?
Thanks

```js
function newDate(days) {
 return moment().add(days, 'd').toDate();
}

const lineData = {
  labels: null,
  datasets: 
  [
    {
      label: 'A',
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "hsl(50, 50%, 80%)",
      data: 
      [
        {
          x: newDate(1),
          y: 12
        },
        {
          x: newDate(2),
          y: 15
        }, 
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'B',
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "hsl(250, 50%, 80%)",
      data: 
      [
        {
          x: newDate(0),
          y: 23
        },
        {
          x: newDate(2),
          y: 34
        },
        {
          x: newDate(3),
          y: 45
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
}

const lineOptions = {
type: 'bar',
 data: lineData,
 options: 
 {
  title: 
  {
 display: true,
  text: 'STACKED TRUE'
},
 legend: 
 {
     display: true,
 },
 hover: 
 {
  mode: 'nearest'
 },
 fill: false,
 responsive: true,
 scales: 
 {
 xAxes: 
 [
   {
    stacked: true,
    display: true,
    ticks: 
    {       
     beginAtZero: false,
    },
    scaleLabel: 
    {
     display: true,
     labelString: "Day",
    },
    barThickness: 15,
    type: 'time',
    distribution: 'linear',
    bounds: 'ticks',
    time: 
    {
     unit: 'day',
     unitStepSize: 1,
     displayFormats: 
     {
      'day': 'DD/MM',
     },
     tooltipFormat: 'DD/MM',
    }
   }
  ],
  yAxes: 
  [
   {
    ticks: 
    {
     beginAtZero: true,
    },
    display: true,
    stacked: true,
    scaleLabel: 
    {
     display: true,
     labelString: "Items",
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 tooltips: 
 {
  mode: 'x',
 },
}
}
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"), lineOptions);


const lineOptions2 = {
 type: 'bar',
 data: lineData,
 options: 
 {
  title: 
  {
   display: true,
    text: 'STACKED FALSE'
  },
 legend: 
 {
  display: true
 },
 hover: 
 {
  mode: 'nearest'
 },
 fill: false,
 responsive: true,
 scales: 
 {
  xAxes: 
  [
   {
    //stacked: true,
    display: true,
    ticks: 
    {       
     beginAtZero: false,
    },
    scaleLabel: 
    {
     display: true,
     labelString: "Day",
    },
    barThickness: 15,
    type: 'time',
    distribution: 'linear',
    bounds: 'ticks',
    time: 
    {
     unit: 'day',
     unitStepSize: 1,
     displayFormats: 
     {
      'day': 'DD/MM',
     },
     tooltipFormat: 'DD/MM',
    }
   }
  ],
  yAxes: 
  [
   {
    ticks: 
    {
     beginAtZero: true,
    },
    display: true,
    //stacked: true,
    scaleLabel: 
    {
     display: true,
     labelString: "Items",
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 tooltips: 
 {
  mode: 'x',
 },
}
}
const chart2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d"), lineOptions2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <canvas id="chart2" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tgfy6q82/42/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both `xAxes` and `yAxes` set to `stacked:true`.

Commenting out `stacked:true` on the `yAxes` will do the trick;

```js
function newDate(days) {
    return moment().add(days, 'd').toDate();
}

const lineData = {
    labels: null,
    datasets: [{
            label: 'A',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "hsl(50, 50%, 80%)",
            data: [{
                    x: newDate(1),
                    y: 12
                },
                {
                    x: newDate(2),
                    y: 15
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            label: 'B',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "hsl(250, 50%, 80%)",
            data: [{
                    x: newDate(0),
                    y: 23
                },
                {
                    x: newDate(2),
                    y: 34
                },
                {
                    x: newDate(3),
                    y: 45
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
}

const lineOptions = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: lineData,
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'STACKED TRUE'
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest'
        },
        fill: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Day",
                },
                barThickness: 15,
                type: 'time',
                distribution: 'linear',
                bounds: 'ticks',
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    unitStepSize: 1,
                    displayFormats: {
                        'day': 'DD/MM',
                    },
                    tooltipFormat: 'DD/MM',
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
                display: true,
                // stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Items",
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'x',
        },
    }
}
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"), lineOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Alternatively, since setting `yAxes` `stacked:true` should be intended, data can be updated such that there exists data for `A` and `B`, even if one of them is 0. https://jsfiddle.net/zqrp0w76/2/

Comment: Ok, your solution is good, but with yAxes stacked:false, the height of the bar is not calculate as the total of the single day, but all datasets is only stacked one in front of of the other, i need all dataset one above the other.

Comment: @user473349 If you want to leave yAxes stacked:true, you can fix your data to include days where one colour has 0. https://jsfiddle.net/zqrp0w76/2/
Updated the answer~

Comment: So its not possible without editing the datasets,for use stacked with x,y axis the dataset's lenght must be the same.

Comment: Your data sets should have the same dates regardless since it's just cleaner data. But yes, something has to change for a fix to occur.

Comment: Ok, this involves some work to do, since in production the data comes from ajax. Further work will be done via javascript to make all the datasets with the same dates. I will suggest a change to the chart.js team.
Thanks for your replies.